# Comunicação entre páginas via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, app

Estou desenvolvendo um web app, onde cada página tem uma opção para filtrar, por exemplo, uma para marcas, depois os modelos dessas marcas, após, os carros e depois os anos do carro escolhido.

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de comunicar essas páginas passando as opções escolhidas em cada página sem utilizar ***PHP***, somente ***HTML*** e ***JavaScript***.

Abrindo uma outra janela até consigo, utilizando por exemplo, o código abaixo:

```
function selectCarro(carro){
  window.marca = carro;
  var b = window.open("modelos.html");
  $(b).load(function(){
  b.marca = marca;
  b.atualiza();
  return;
  });
}
```

O problema é se abrir a página na mesma janela, por exemplo com `window.location` ou com open utilizando `_self`.

Alguma solução??

Comment: Procure por Session e Cookies em JavaScript que pode ajudar muito você nessa tarefa.

Comment: Obrigado, vou pesquisar por isso e ver se encontro a solução.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma opção que eu sempre sugiro nesses casos é o [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) e que [funciona em todos os browser mais usados](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

O localStorage salva uma [DOM string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) onde você pode colocar não só strings mas também objetos utilizando [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) e [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Esses dados são salvos sob seu domínio e podem ser usados em diferentes abas/janelas se forem no mesmo navegador. Os dados não expiram a menos que sejam limpos via código ou pelo usuário, utilizando a ferramenta de desenvolvedores do navegador. Caso você deseje que esses dados sejam limpos ao fechar o navegador, basta simplesmente utilizar o [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), que apaga os dados com o fim da sessão.

Exemplo simples de uso:

```
var filtros = [{
    marca: "VW",
    ano: "2015",
    modelo: "Gol"
}];

localStorage.setItem("filtros", JSON.stringify(filtros));

var filtrosSalvos = localStorage.getItem("filtros");

console.log("filtrosSalvos", filtrosSalvos);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pf6k23/)**</kbd>

Comment: Valeu mano, vou testar aqui !!

Comment: Deu certo !!! Utilizei localStorage mesmo ! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @ErasmoNeto ok. Precisando estamos aí.